# What's the easiest way to circulate air in the attic of my garage?

Tags: insulation, garage, attic, woodworking, workshop

I have an unfinished attached ~20'x20' two car garage and I would like to finish it so I can use 1 bay as a wood shop year-round. I live in Missoula, MT and really just want to keep it above ~40F in the winter, probably with some space heaters.

My plan was to insulate the garage door and insulate/sheetrock the walls and roof joists. Currently there are no soffit vents or ridge vents of any kind in the garage, and I'm worried about moisture/head build up in the garage attic between the insulation and the roof.

How big of a problem would that moisture/heat build up be? It can get hot here in the summers and the garage gets a lot of sunlight. I'm also worried about creating ice dams in the winter.

I would like to do all the work myself and was thinking that the simplest solution would be to install soffit vents and add a fan with some ducting to pull hot air from the top of the attic space down some of the soffits. Does that sound like a good solution?

Comment: Is there a ceiling on your garage now and is the attic fully enclosed (no vents, fans, etc.)?

Comment: Currently there is no ceiling. It's just the roof trusses. I would be attaching the drywall to the bottom of those trusses, effectively creating an attic instead of one big space like it is now.

Comment: Hot air rises.  the most simple way is to add soffit vents and a ridge vent.  The air will do all the work without any fancy duct work or power needed.

Comment: Space heaters (presumably electric resistance) are an expensive way to heat a shop (even just to above 40°F) in a place as cold as Missoula, MT unless your electricity rates are abnormally low.

Comment: That's a good point about the passive system. I was hoping to avoid adding a ridge vent because I'm not sure if that's something I can do myself, but it's probably worth it anyway. 

I was only planning on running the heaters while I was in the garage. What would be a better/cheaper heating option? It looks like the most efficient options have a large upfront cost that would take years to break even.